# Convert <video> time values to 2 decimal places

Tags: jquery, video, time

I am trying to extract duration and currentTime values from a HTML5 video. I have managed to do this successfully, however the values are output in long strings, whereas I would like 2 decimal places. In addition, rather than only displaying seconds, I would like to convert both times to a human readable format i.e mm:ss

For example, rather than 4.366561 / 87.445 I want to display 00:04 / 01:27

Finally, the current Time value is updated as the video progresses, so the solution needs to take this into account.

Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<video id="video" src="video-url.com" preload></video>
<span class="current">0:00s</span> <span>/</span> <span class="duration">0:00s</span>
```

**Jquery**

```
var video = $('#video');

$(video).on('loadedmetadata', function() {
  $('.duration').text(video[0].duration);
});

// Update video current time as video plays
$(video).on('timeupdate', function() {
  $('.current').text(video[0].currentTime);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using division and module calculations:

```js
let current = 4.366561;
let duration = 87.445;

function prettyTime(t) {
  let minutes = Math.floor(t / 60);
  if (minutes<10) minutes = '0' + minutes;
  let seconds = Math.floor(t % 60);
  if (seconds<10) seconds = '0' + seconds;
  return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}

console.log( prettyTime(current) );
console.log( prettyTime(duration) );
```

**Example:**

```js
function prettyTime(t) {
  let minutes = Math.floor(t / 60);
  if (minutes<10) minutes = '0' + minutes;
  let seconds = Math.floor(t % 60);
  if (seconds<10) seconds = '0' + seconds;
  return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}

let video = $('#video');

$(video).on('loadedmetadata', function() {
  $('.duration').text( prettyTime(video[0].duration) );
});

$(video).on('timeupdate', function() {
  $('.current').text( prettyTime(video[0].currentTime) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>

<br>
<span class="current">00:00</span> <span>/</span> <span class="duration">00:00</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Jan - this looks like it will work very well. However, I'm having trouble integrating with my own code. Could you help to implement with my code, including ensuring the current variable gets updated correctly as the video plays? Many thanks!

Comment: @dungey_140 I've added an example. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Almost seems perfect. However, $('.duration').text( prettyTime(video[0].duration) ); seems inconsistent, it that it sometimes returns the correct duration, but other times does not. I cannot find any pattern explaining this. Is there anything obvious in the code that might help? Finally, I'm getting some compiling errors on the 'let' elements - can these be swapped out for 'var, for example?

Comment: You can replace `let` with `var`. -- The inconsistency of duration could possibly a result of missing the `loadedmetadata`-event. Then it will stay at 00:00. If that's the case you could update the duration together with the current-value in when the `timeupdate` event happens.

Comment: Hey @jan - thanks for this tip. Can you explain why a loadedmetadata event might get missed? Is there anyway of improving this?

Comment: It could get missed if the metadata gets loaded before the event-listener is attached to the video-element.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can use this function to format your number to `MM:SS`

```
function formatTime(time) {
  if (time < 5999) {
    // MM:SS
    var minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
    var seconds = Math.round(time - (minutes * 60));

    if (minutes < 10) { minutes = "0" + minutes }
    if (seconds < 10) { seconds = "0" + seconds }

    return minutes + ":" + seconds + "s"
  } else {
    return "Exceeds time"
  }
};
```

Here is an example:

```js
var current = 4.366561;
var duration = 87.445;

$('.duration').text(formatTime(duration));
$('.current').text(formatTime(current));


function formatTime(time) {
  if (time < 5999) {
    // MM:SS
    var minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
    var seconds = Math.round(time - (minutes * 60));

    if (minutes < 10) { minutes = "0" + minutes }
    if (seconds < 10) { seconds = "0" + seconds }

    return minutes + ":" + seconds + "s"
  } else {
    return "Exceeds time"
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="current">0:00s</span>
<span class="duration">0:00s</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

.toFixed() is the solution

```
$(video).on('timeupdate', function() {
  $('.current').text(video[0].currentTime.toFixed(2));
});
```